# How do I get information on resolutions and positions from multiple monitors in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, maui, maui-windows

I'm writing a cross-platform application in .Net MAUI. When the application is running on a Windows desktop computer it should show a canvas which stretches across multiple monitors. To be able to draw on the correct pixel positions on this canvas I need the resolutions and positions of all connected monitors.

In Windows Forms it is possible to get information for multiple monitors using `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`. From this I can then get the positions and resolutions of all connected monitors.
So far, in MAUI I've only been able to find `DeviceDisplay` to get resolution for a single screen.

How do I get positions and resolutions for multiple monitors in .Net MAUI?
Is it possible to do from within the framework, or do I need to go through the Win32 API?

Comment: You will have to write your own API that does this since this a Platform specific thing you won't find cross-platform APIs doing this

Comment: @FreakyAli It's rather odd that your rationale for this particular feature not being available is that it would require a platform-agnostic API over platform-specific implementations. Which is *exactly* what MAUI is.

Comment: @IInspectable All I meant was this won't be a readily available API(From the MAUI Framework) since its not a feature that is common in ALL PLATFORMS, Most Maui APIs are Platform Agnostic so that you can use it and it will return you data based on platforms, This is Specific to Win Forms... So he just needs to use a DI or a Partial class and get execute the platform API to get what he wants

Comment: @IInspectable - you have misread FreakyAli's comment. You are in agreement with FreakyAli that Maui would have platform-agnostic APIs, but not platform-specific ones.

Comment: @Johan - a `Windows` API yes, a `Win32` API no. Inside `Windows` folder, or in the main project folder inside `#if Windows`, you can make `WinUI 3` (aka `Windows Desktop App`) calls.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I don't see what's any more platform-specific about enumerating display devices than, say, accessing any given windowing system service. There's nothing inherent to the problem of enumerating display devices that would prevent an implementation from reporting the results. It's not like passing rectangle coordinates over an interface were somehow platform-specific. So, no, I certainly do not agree with that comment.

Comment: Ok. Now it is clear what you are saying. The historical reason is that Maui is derived from XForms, which started on devices that only had a single screen. The philosophy of development has been to ONLY support a feature that exists on ALL supported platforms. It’s been difficult enough for the devs to get this basic set of functionality to work everywhere. They are not there yet. Adding a feature such as this would be premature, IMHO. Add a feature request as an issue at Maui GitHub. (Or use WINUI 3 instead of Maui, and only target Windows for now. Port later.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve What call would I make in WinUI code? The platform-specific method I have in my mind is otherwise to P/Invoke the Win32 API, calling `EnumDisplayDevices` or similar.

Comment: I don't know. Bottom line is code in `Windows` folder, or inside `#if Windows` is `WinUI 3` ("Windows Desktop App") code. Research that. I assume you can still P/Invoke, but there likely is an appropriate API. Shouldn't need to P/Invoke any more, except for very rare uses. Also look into .Net 7, and future roadmap. Sounds like a call that should exist on all desktop platforms, not too far in the future. Independently of Maui, perhaps.